# Disable caroufredsel at particular event

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I am using caroufredsel in my website, I only want it to active/ work when windows width is less 960px. 
It is working when good, I re size browser window, when it is less then 960px it start working, But problem is when I again re size window it do not disable even when width is more then 960px,

**Is there any way to disable caroufredsel when windows width is more the 959px?**

*Here is my code:*

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    if($(window).width() <=959)
    {
        $('.item-holder').addClass('item-carousel');
        $('.item-carousel').carouFredSel(
        {
            width: "100%",
            height:200,
            circular: true,
            auto    : false,
        });

        $('#portfolio-wrapper .carousel-nav').show();

    }
    else
    {
        $('.item-holder').removeClass('item-carousel');
        $('.item-carousel').carouFredSel(false);
        $('#portfolio-wrapper .carousel-nav').hide();
    }
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable that gets the content of the parent of the carousel.

> var carouselContent = $('.item-carousel').parent().html();

Then, when you want to disable carouFredSel do this:

> $('.item-carousel').parent().empty().html(carouselContent );

Also, you can target the parent directly and not bother with the parent() selector. I've only used it in my example because i don't know the class name or id of the parent element.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
 $(".item-carousel").trigger("destroy");
```

instead of

```
$('.item-carousel').carouFredSel(false);
```

Comment: Maybe it's not working because you are removing the class "item-carousel" before triggering the destroy event. Delete the "removeclass" line to see if it works.

Comment: Yep, removing the class and then trying to call the method on the object without the class doesn't work. However, leaving it in place and hitting destroy does work.